# How to modify the object within its own class?

Tags: java

How do you modify and object within its own class in Java?

ex:

```
public Node()
//constructs a new node

public void setNode(Node n)
***this.node** = this.right; //How do you modify the node within its same class?
```

Comment: is ``this.node`` even a field? Or is this question about whether you can do something like ``this = this.right;``? You can't.

Comment: So it's impossible to do something like this = this.right?

Comment: Yes, it's impossible.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly change an object. You can modify it by changing its components, since an object is a **composite type**, i.e, it is made by combining some **primitive types**

eg:

This is not possible:

```
public void setNode(Node n)
{
    this = n;
}
```

But, you can do this:

```
public void setNode(Node n)
{
    this.x = n.x;
    this.y = n.y;
    this.z = n.z;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! So it's basically like doing a deep copy?